# Rails not save data in DB (with Angular)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have problem with save data in DB. 
This is my **orders_controller:**

```
def create
    order = meal.build_order(order_params)
    respond_with order
end
```

Function in **orders factory:**

```
o.create = function(order) {
    return $http.post('/orders.json', order).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      o.orders.push(data);
    });
};
```

Call orders.create in **ordersCtrl** (in angular controller)

```
if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.meal)) {
    orders.create({
      meal_id: $scope.meal.id,
      status: "ordered",
    });
}
```

What can be wrong with that code? When I've wrote **order.save** in Rails controller - order has been saved.

Comment: Your question is misleading. the title says **Rails not save data in DB** but then you explicitly say in the description **When I've wrote order.save in Rails controller - order has been saved.**. which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html):

`build_association(attributes = {})`

Returns a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but has not yet been saved.

So basically when you use `build_order` it is not saving it (and this is how rails works). You could use `create_order`.